# Why does this function compile flowlessly but Modelsim refuses to simulate it?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

So i'm trying to use that function i wrote to convert a binary coding (3 bits) into a onehot coding (8 bits). The whole compilation process from analysis and synthesis to netlist in Quartus shows no error, the Modelsim build doesn't show any error aswell. But when i'm testing the component which uses this function, the simulation just stops whenever it encounters a call to the function. It's not even returning an error, the simulation process just doesn't go further.
It seems like the problem comes from the loop itself because when i put its content in comment it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

```
FUNCTION ONEHOT (adBin : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) 
    RETURN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR IS
    VARIABLE onehot : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    VARIABLE bitPos : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 8 := 0;
BEGIN

    onehot := (OTHERS => '0');

    FOR i IN adBin'range LOOP
      IF adBin(i) = '1' THEN
        bitPos := bitPos + 2**i;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    onehot(bitPos-1) := '1';

    RETURN onehot;

END FUNCTION;
```

Also iv'e tried using a CASE instruction in that function to avoid using maths but it tells me "Array type case expression must be of a locally static subtype." but i don't know what this means...

```
FUNCTION ONEHOT (adBin : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) 
        RETURN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR IS
        VARIABLE onehot : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        VARIABLE bitPos : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 8 := 0;
    BEGIN

        onehot := (OTHERS => '0');

        CASE adBin IS
            WHEN "000" => onehot(0) := '1';
            WHEN "001" => onehot(1) := '1';
            WHEN "010" => onehot(2) := '1';
            WHEN "011" => onehot(3) := '1';
            WHEN "100" => onehot(4) := '1';
            WHEN "101" => onehot(5) := '1';
            WHEN "110" => onehot(6) := '1';
            WHEN "111" => onehot(7) := '1';
            WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
        END CASE;

        RETURN onehot;

    END FUNCTION;
```

Thank you for any help

Edit: It seems like the error comes from the exponential 2**i.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. The first function compiles 'flowlessly' because range checking is a runtime (simulation) operation. It appears NoRangeCheck is enabled or you'd get a error message. The second function's vcom error occurs because the set of values for the case expression must be known at analysis time, the parameter is specified without a subtype indication constraint. If onehot has a locally static index range  so should AdBin. There's a matching element requirement in the association between the formal (AdBin) and the actual  in a function call, no requirement index ranges are identical.

Comment: Iv'e found out it's actualy the 2**0 which does not compute so i made a separate case for this one. I should have expected it but, still strange. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Two the zeroth power is one (It does compute). What value of adBin fails and what is it's index range? Most simulators flush output, report statements occurring before a failure will show up on the console.

Comment: You have no initial value for `bitPos` like you have for `onehot`. As for the error message in the second one, I am not that familiar with VHDL so can't help you.

Comment: bitPos has an intial value of 0.  A function's declarative items (bitPos) are dynamically elaborated each time the function is called (IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.6 Dynamic elaboration, para 2 b) "...Finally, if the designator of the subprogram is not decorated with the 'FOREIGN attribute defined in package STANDARD, the declarative part of the corresponding subprogram body is elaborated and the sequence of statements in the subprogram body is execute. ..."). Oldfart is correct to the extent he admits not being that familiar with VHDL.

Comment: Ok, i was trying to initialise `bitPos` in the declaration but it wasn't working. I just initialise it directly into the function and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Note there is a second problem in the first function body : given (others => '0') as input, there is an out of range array access to onehot.

Comment: `i was trying to initialise bitPos in the declaration but it wasn't working. ` Yes it does work. The declaration is elaborated each function call. [The actual error in your first shown function onehot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCPRs.jpg). Provide a [mcve].